# Replacing a string in VI Editor

Tags: vi

I am trying to replace a specific letter (say 'b') in my code with 'beta'. However, there are a lot of words which has 'b' occurring in them, so if I use `:/g/b/s//beta/g` all the 'b' in those words also get replaced. Using `gc` instead of `g` doesn't really help either, since it is a 2,000 line code and there are just too many to do.

Is there a way by which I can choose to replace the strings which only has 'b' in them and and ignore every other string?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Do you want something like `:%s/\<b\>/beta/gc`?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what was required.
Thank you so much! :)